# How to pass list <object> between fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, parse-platform

I've created my layout with viewPager and TabLayout:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
{


public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 3 ;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,false);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    int [] drawables = {R.drawable.home,R.drawable.street,R.drawable.map};

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    final SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
    final CardFragment cardFragment = new CardFragment();
    final MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();

    viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager())
    {
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            if(position == 0)
             return searchFragment;
            else if(position ==1)
             return cardFragment;
            else
             return mapFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return int_items;
        }
    });

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++)
    {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(drawables[i]);
    }

    return inflatedView;

}





    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {

        super.onAttach(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

    }
}
```

now I need to do this code in Asynctask (I post only doInBackground() method):

```
List <ParseObject> result;
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query;

 protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params)
 {
   try
   {
      query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Trains");
      result = query.find();

   }
   catch (com.parse.ParseException e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

so now I want to pass `List <ParseObject> result;` at `SearchFragment`, `CardFragment` and `MapFragment`.

It's possible to use a Bundle? Or have I to use other method?

Comment: yes its good way if ParseObject data is implements Serializable then you can use Bundle its better approach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As most of the developers are confused with performance parameters of Serialization and Parcelable, Im putting the explanation below

- Comparison of Parceleable and Serialization with performance results [Comparison b/w Parcelable and Serialization](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)
- Inorder to simplify parcelable implementation , there are plugin's available for IDE's Refer [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable) for naXa's Answer
- Plugin for Parcelable generator [Android Studio Plugin for Android Parcelable boilerplate code generation](https://github.com/mcharmas/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin)

Now comes how to implement Parceleable interface

Create object class which you want to pass implement `Parcelable` interface

```
public class ContactPojo implements Parcelable{
       private String name;
       private String job_title;
       public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
       }

       public void setJob_title(String job_title) {
        this.job_title = job_title;
       }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getJob_title() {
        return job_title;
    }
    private ContactPojo(Parcel parcel){
        name=parcel.readString();
        job_title=parcel.readString();
    }
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeString(job_title);
    }
public static final Parcelable.Creator<ContactPojo> CREATOR = new
            Parcelable.Creator<ContactPojo>() {
                public ContactPojo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                    return new ContactPojo(in);
                }

                public ContactPojo[] newArray(int size) {
                    return new ContactPojo[size];
    }};
}
```

Now populate the pojo class by the doing the following

```
ContactPojo contactPojo= new ContactPojo();
contactPojo.setName("name");
contactPojo.setJob_title("name");
```

send it to next intent by this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, DetailView.class);
intent.putExtra("Data", contactPojo);
```

Retrieval of data in next intent by next steps

```
ContactPojo contactPojo=new ContactPojo();
contactPojo=getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Data");
Log.i(AppConstants.APPUILOG, "Name: " + contactPojo.getName() );
```

Comment: if I use intent means to pass data from activities sure? and if I want to pass data only to fragments? Because I need the same List< > in these three fragments

Comment: @Stallion Out of curiosity.. Why not `Serialization`  Ain't we use `getArguments()` Instead of getIntent() in Fragments?

Comment: @ste9206  ` roomObject = (ResultPojo) getArguments().getSerializable(
                "result"); ` you can get the array list like this in fragment.

Comment: @RethinavelPillai so I have to use a bundle?

Comment: @ste9206 Yes you should.. It is recommended. And i personally feel that `Parcelable` is `Expensive` rather than `serialization`.

Comment: Android standard is Parcelable than Serialization. Serialization is Java standard. http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Comment: @RethinavelPillai and to set Argument? I have to call Bundle bundle = new Bundle( ) and then ?

Comment: @ste9206 check my edit specifying performance and implementation simplification with plugins

Comment: @ste9206 
`DocumentFragment docsFragment = new DocumentFragment();
   Bundle docsBundle = new Bundle();
   docsBundle.putSerializable("roomsAl", roomsAl);
   docsBundle.putSerializable("documentsAl", documentsAl);
   docsFragment.setArguments(docsBundle);`

Comment: @Stallion Thanks.. I went through the link. It was quite useful. Thanks. My bad i didn't know that..

Comment: @Stallion but I have to use also a bundle?

Comment: @ste9206 Not mandatory. You can go through the explanation which I have given. Its self explanatory !

Answer (score -2):

Just do like this i also used it.
Create one class of object which list you want to pass

```
public class PostDetails implements Serializable {
private String postUrl;
private String postType;
public String getPostUrl() {
return postUrl;
}

/**
* 
* @param postUrl
* The post_url
*/
public void setPostUrl(String postUrl) {
this.postUrl = postUrl;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The postType
*/
public String getPostType() {
return postType;
}

/**
* 
* @param postType
* The post_type
*/
public void setPostType(String postType) {
this.postType = postType;
}

}
```

In intent just put

```
List<PostDetails> postDetailses;
intent.putExtra("vdata", (Serializable) postDetailses);
```

For Receiving at activity side

```
postDetailsList= (List<PostDetails>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("vdata");
```