# Android, performance of transferring data between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization

Which one of two ways below has better performance for transferring data between activities?

1. `Activity1:` `putExtra("id" , customerId)`

   `Activity2:` Select on the table and fill `Customer` object
2. `Activity1:` `putExtra("customer", customer)`

   `Activity2:` `Customer customer = (Customer)getIntent().getExtras().getSerialaizable("customer");`

I mean send a unique item (like id) to the next activity and then select it from data base OR send the whole object to the next activity and cast it?

Comment: depends on what you want in your next activity. If you only want a single id then why send all data of Customer to next activity.

Comment: @VivekMishra Of course I want whole data of object!

Comment: then send the whole object

Comment: The answer in this link will be helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208243/how-to-pass-list-object-between-fragment/37208349#37208349

Answer (score 1):

Obviously first way. You just send the ID of the object and then read it from the database in second `Activity`. The other way involves serialization/deserialization which costs CPU-cycles. Even using `Parcelable` will still use significant CPU-cycles.

On the other hand, I doubt that you would notice any performance penalties unless you are doing this for a bazillion objects. Do whatever is more straightforward and easier to understand/maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Serializable is not recommended in android, check [parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) it's [faster](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/).

Serialization vs DB depends on object complicity, only profiling can show the picture, but for a one object it's neglectable.

The fastest way would be to store object in memory and share through singleton.